# Minimum Intent when saying God's Name in prayer service

Tags: halacha, tefilla, shemos-sacred-names

In the daily prayers one has to recite many psalms and other prayers containing God's Name.

What is the minimum intent one must have in order to not be transgressing any biblical or rabbinical precept.

Are there leniencies in this when in a fast moving minyan?

Answer (score 1):

The Mishnah Berurah in [O"C 5 s"k 3](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%94_%D7%90#.D7.92_.D7.9E.D7.91) says the minimum requirement for the Tetragrammaton is "master of all" except for the first verse of Shema where one also needs to have in mind "Who was, is and will be".

Comment: do you have to think about this when saying it or can you just know that this is what it means and read it without thought

Comment: It looks like in that spot, you need to actively think it.